# exam documentclass automated \choice on emacs auctex

Tags: emacs, auctex, exam

I am using the `exam` class to write some multiple choice questions on emacs. How can I achieve some sort of automatic `\choice` key combination in the `checkboxes` environment etc. Just like that I can use `M-RET` to achieve automatic `\item` in the `itemize` or `enumerate` environment?

In fact, some days ago I accidentally found out that I can use `M-j` to get what I want, but I lost it soon afterwards, and sadly I cannot regenerated the situation ever again. Do I need to activate something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hack `LaTeX-item-list`.  Honestly, this is a bit uncomfortable to do because it should be a task for [style files](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Simple-Style).

Anyway, you can add the following lines to your init file

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        ;; Add checkboxes
        (add-to-list
         'LaTeX-item-list
         '("checkboxes" . (lambda ()
                (let (TeX-insert-braces)
                  (TeX-insert-macro "choice ")))))
        ;; Add choices
        (add-to-list
         'LaTeX-item-list
         '("choices" . (lambda ()
                 (let (TeX-insert-braces)
                   (TeX-insert-macro "choice ")))))))
```

In this way, you can type <kbd>C-c C-j</kbd> in `choices` and `checkboxes` environments and a newline will be inserted, with new line starting with `\choice`.

I did it only for a couple of environments, if you want to include others follow the example for `checkboxes`.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/20361826

Comment: this is great! by any chance do you know some possibility how got it by accident before? i did not add anything related to choice or checkboxes before. as you mentioned, is there a style file for `exam`? thanks~

Comment: `C-c C-j` will always insert `\item` as if point were in an `itemize` environment, unless it is in another environment listed in `LaTeX-item-list`.  Unfortunately not, AUCTeX doesn't provide an `exam` style file, I could try writing down one some day.